# How to configure jenkins pipeline with logstash plugin?

Tags: elasticsearch, jenkins-pipeline, logstash, kibana

Usecase: I want to send jenkins job console log to elasticsearch, from there to kibana so that i can visualise the data.

I am using logstash plugin to achieve this. For freestyle job logstash plugin configuration is working fine but for jenkins pipeline jobs I am getting all required data like build number, job name, build duration and all but it is not showing the build result i.e., success or failure it is not showing.

I tried in two ways:
1.

```
 stage('send to ES') {
       logstashSend failBuild: true, maxLines: -1
}
```

2.

```
timestamps {
  logstash {
    node() {
      sh'''
        echo 'Hello, World!'
      '''
      try {
        stage('GitSCM')
    {
        git url: 'github repo.git'
    }
    stage('Initialize')
    {

        jdk = tool name: 'jdk'
        env.JAVA_HOME = "${jdk}"
        echo "jdk installation path is: ${jdk}"
        sh "${jdk}/bin/java -version"
        sh '$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version'
        def mvnHome = tool 'mvn'
    }

     stage('Build Stage')
    {
        def mvnHome = tool 'mvn'
        sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn -B verify"
    }
        currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
      } catch (Exception err) {
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
      }    
    }
  }
}
```

But in both ways I am not getting build result i.e., success or failure in my elasticsearch or kibana.
Can someone help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a clear way to do that, my solution was add those lines at the end of the Jenkinsfile:

```
echo "Current result: ${currentBuild.currentResult}" 
logstashSend failBuild: true, maxLines: 3
```

In my case, I dont need it to send all console logs, only one log with the result per job.